# Wrapping async functions with callbacks within

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I need to call two async functions sequentially inside a new function. Both functions use callbacks to perform asynchronous operations.

When I just call my functions one by one I am faced with the problem that, as I understand it, they are called synchronously, and the second function does not wait for the first to execute

How can I wrap them to be performed sequentially?

Code that I have:

```
let firstFunction = (data, callback) => {

    DBCallingFirst
    .asyncMethodFirst(resultObj, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      // Some code
    });
}

let secondFunction = (data, callback) => {

    DBCallingSecond
    .asyncMethodSecond(resultObj, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);

      // Some code
    });
}

let newFunction = (data, callback) => {

    firstFunction(data, callback);
    
    secondFunction(data, callback);
}
```

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use promises, or async/await, you can make this a lot cleaner.  As it is, you can just do the second db operation in the callback from the first one - so that guarantees the first one completes before calling the second

```
    let firstFunction = async (data, callback) => {

    DBCallingFirst
    .asyncMethodFirst(resultObj, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      DBCallingSecond
        .asyncMethodSecond(resultObj, (err, result) => {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          // Some code
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT: With promises, you could structure it like this:

```
let firstFunction = (data) => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    DBCallingFirst
      .asyncMethodFirst(data, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return Promise.reject();
        }
        return Promise.resolve(result);
      });
  });
}

let secondFunction = (data) => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    DBCallingSecond
    .asyncMethodSecond(data, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      return Promise.resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

let newFunction = (data, callback) => {

  firstFunction(data).then((result1) => {
    secondFunction(data).then(result2) {

    }).catch(err2) {
      console.error(err2);
    });
  }.catch((err1) => {
    console.error(err1);
  });
}
```

Comment: I need to stick with clear structure. I just invoke the first function, than I invoke the second one and all these operations are performing inside new function
Can I wrap both functions to return new Promise and then invoke them sequentially?
If I can, how should I do this?

Comment: Updated with promises

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Return Promise from both the functions and await them like this

```
const firstFunction = (data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    DBCallingFirst.asyncMethodFirst(data, (err, result) => {
       if(err) reject(err);
       resolve(result);
    })
  })
}

    const secondFunction = (data) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        DBCallingSecond.asyncMethodSecond(data, (err, result) => {
           if(err) reject(err);
           resolve(result);
         })
      })
    }
```

Now you can call both of them sequentially using await

```
const newFunction = async (data) => { // note the async part in function definition
  try {
     const result1 = await firstFunction(data);
     const result2 = await secondFunction(data); // this will be executed only after firstFunction resolves/rejects;
  } catch (err) { 
    console.log('Error from the function', error) // promise rejection will be caught here
  } 
   
}
```

Comment: This one is clean, I liked the solution !!